# Determining if an array of strings contains a certain substring in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a simple ruby question.  I have an array of strings.  I'd like to determine if that array contains a substring of any of the strings. As an example

```
a = ['cat','dog','elephant']
a.to_s.include?('ele')
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you want to get `true` or `false` for `['cat','dog','elephant']` and `'gel'`?

Comment: any idea on how to get array of elements that  has the substring?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`a.any?` should do the job.

```
> a = ['cat','dog','elephant']
=> ["cat", "dog", "elephant"]
> a.any? { |s| s.include?('ele') }
=> true
> a.any? { |s| s.include?('nope') }
=> false
```

Comment: Is there a way to check multiple values ?

Comment: You'd need to do a nested `any?` check and probably a different question although a short answer might be: `a.any? { |s| ['aba', 'ele'].any? { |t| s.include?(t) } }`

Comment: I ended with this `haystack.select { |str| str.include?('wat') || str.include?('pre') }`

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 14):

Here is one more way:
if you want to get that affected string element.

```
>  a = ['cat','dog','elephant']
=> ["cat", "dog", "elephant"]
> a.grep(/ele/)
=> ["elephant"]
```

if you just want Boolean value only.

```
> a.grep(/ele/).empty?
=> false # it return false due to value is present
```

Hope this is helpful.